# Ubuntu installation on my system

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I am installing Ubuntu OS in virtual box. I have 32 bit intel system with 3 GB RAM. So can I install i386 ubuntu OS?

Comment: you can and go ahead..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the 32-bit version. Although techincally possible, it is very hard to emulate an x86_64 (64-bit) architecture with a 32-bit processor. Some processors might support this, but I would recommend going with the 32-bit option.